# I can't find the mobi format ebooks I copied from my computer to my kindle via usb, what should I do?

Tags: kindle, mobi

Transferring ebooks in mobi file to my kindle used to be hassle free. I just drag it to the "documents" folder and voilà! They're there.

What happened yesterday was different. I tried to move mobi ebooks to my kindle. The books were  transferred fine, I can see them on my kindle drive on the computer. The problem was when I opened my Kindle to arrange the books I transferred, they weren't there. I tried reconnecting my kindle to the computer and the books are still there. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I don't have a kindle, so I am not sure what causes the software on it to rescan the drive. Normally, on other ebook readers, this is done once based on disconnecting the USB, and the software tells you it is scanning. Try to connect using USB and disconnect. If that doesn't work a restart of the machine might help. As for the cause, my guesses are a software glitch, or a reset time on the device.

Comment: Are you sure the .mobi documents are fine? Maybe they're corrupted, or perhaps were corrupted once transferred. How much free space remains in your device?

Comment: What kind of Kindle are we talking about? The Fire interface is different than the Kindle DX or Paperwhite interface.

Comment: You can use SENDTOKINDLE app, can't you?

Comment: Try and use Calibre to transfer them and see if that doesn't work.

Comment: Calibre transfer ebooks just by moving files around, just like the default file manager; it is unlikely that using it in this situation could help him; moreover, his problem is to have the Kindle detect the books, non transferring them (he said that they were successfully transferred).

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I download free ebooks directly to my low cost fire and it does not recognize the book. i can open and read but once i leave i lose my book settings. I may have to move all my books to desktop first and use calibre to format and transfer.

Comment: I have the same problem and have pushed all the buttons. I had 246 books before I did a hard restart now I have 15 showing. I checked the docs file on the computer and everything is still there just not showing in downloads really stumped.

Comment: use the doc tab.  to the left of the sort selection it has another drop down menu to select docs.  This may work for you.

Comment: 8/2023 Kindle fire HDX, FireOS5.7.0.0 still has same issue -- non-drmed mobies don't show up after being copied to Books. They are sometimes accessible via Search (and sometimes not?), then if found, select the book from found list, or ES file explorer (double click to open).  A new mobi book sideloaded via USB never showed up in the Books/downloaded listing, but did show up in the "For Me" tab to the left of "Home" in the  recent listing (cover art and all). Note, I had opened the book via search and ES file explorer before I looked at the "for Me" tab.

Answer (score 3):

File size can be an issue. I've found that if the book's file size is greater than 50MB, the file will transfer to the documents folder on disk, but not appear on the kindle. In my case, I used Calibre to convert mobi to azw3, which reduced the file size, and the book then appeared on my kindle.

Comment: A 50 MB book? That's larger than many games!

Answer (score 1):

Here are my personal suggestions, I'm not sure they work well.

1. Restart you Kindle, then touch home page and select "Docs".

Check whether your books are placed or not.

2: Maybe your Mobi files are not purchased by yourself, which makes that you can copy to Kindle but your Kindle can't recognize it.

3: (If this mobi is purchased by your own account from Amazon)

Maybe Amazon has stopped selling this book any longer, and delete it from their library. If they abandoned one book, this book will disappear from your cloud and devices, because these books are linked to your account by amazon and you haven't back them up.

4. A refer guide [Kindle Transfer](http://www.epubor.com/kindle-ebooks-to-kindle.html) that may help you:

Comment: Restarting the kindle helped in my case. Would like to point out that I am using the new AWS format not the mobi one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why these books aren't showing up, but an alternative method you might try is using the Send to Kindle app from Amazon. There are versions for PC and Mac that you can download at [www.amazon.com/sendtokindle](http://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle).

Comment: Do you need an app? I thought kindle users actually had  an email address, and you could just email an attachment to that address.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly use the email address, with no additional downloads requqired. I prefer the app personally because it integrates with Windows Explorer - when you right-click "Send to Kindle" is one of the options. It's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the books you copied had DRM, in which case the Kindle would not be able to read them.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the settings on your pc, in particular the mobi files themselves. I'm not sure, but I've had "missing" files before. Try right clicking on the file and selecting "properties". From their, on the "General" tab, make sure at bottom (Attributes) the "Hidden" box isn't checked. Also, doing the same (right click / Properties) under "Security" tab make sure you have all "Full Control, Read, Write" etc in "Permissions for SYSTEM" checked to "Allow".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and it can be resolved by choosing **DOWNLOADED** in the left - top corner under home button (it is **ALL | DOWNLOADED** will be there)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue several times. Unfortunately I was not able to resolve this, though I've tried many different things:

- Re-uploading the files again, moving across different folders
- Rebooting kindle
- Checking file permissions and collection views etc.

The only thing, that worked for me, unforturnately, was to do hard-reset, and then upload everything again... (of course firstly I've put copied everything to some backup folder on my PC).

One issue with doing that was that some books even lost progress tracking... and after further analysis it looked to me like there was some format change, e.g. progress files (I think those are files with *.mbs extension) had some hashes (some random set of characters) in their name, which I had to delete and then suddenly progress was visible, etc.

It got me thinking some time later, whether there was maybe some updates along the way, but I did not confirm that...

Anyway - blunt answer for me was: swear a alot, then calm down and backup everything, do hard-reset, upload it back and try to still love your kindle.

Edit: I just found a method that worked for me, move the "books" folder to a different location, restart the books app, maybe restart the kindle, eventually, all the old books will go away from the app's library. Then move the "books" folder back to where it belongs. I restarted the app and the kindle again and read a kindle store book for a while and when I went back to the library, all the mobis were there in the library.

Answer (score -2):

I have had this exact same problem, if you have a paperwhite go to your home page click on 'All Items' then click 'Documents' I found my books in there

On the latest Paperwhite select Home then all then downloaded and they will show up in your library. Also type author's name or book title in search for quick access if you have lots of books.